# Highcharts, mixed stacked & non-stacked columns

Tags: highcharts

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but how can I have a mix of stacked & non-stacked columns?

Here's what I've tired so far:

```
series: [{
    stacking: false,
    data: [10]
}, {
    stacking: 'normal',
    data: [5, 5]
}, {
    stacking: false,
    data: [3]
}]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m67wh8va/1/

I'd like "Oranges + Tangerine" to be stacked & the others without stacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it using `null` points.

**Code:**

```
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      stacking: 'normal'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [null, 1, null, null]
  }, {
    data: [null, 5, null, null]
  }, {
    data: [2, 5, 4, 7]
  }]
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c041dm35/